# PHP: Show <td> elements if certain criteria is true

Tags: php, if-statement, html-table

Basically I need to have the columns with my delete and edit buttons visible only if the admin logs in, I know how to determine if an admin is logged in.  Is there a way to echo the  tags that need to be shown?  Thanks in advance!

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Zip Code</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Edit?</th>
            <th>Delete?</th>
        </tr>        
        <?php foreach ($users as $user) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $user->getUser_id();?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user->getFirstName().' '.$user->getLastName();?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user->getEmailAddress(); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user->getAddress();?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user->getCity(); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user->getState(); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user->getZipCode(); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user->getActiveDescription();?></td>



these two <td> should only be shown if x is true:

            <td>
             <form action ="" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="controllerRequest"
                       value="show_user_edit">
                <input type="hidden" name="user_id"
                       value="<?php echo $user->getUser_id(); ?>"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Edit"></form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="controllerRequest"
                           value="delete_user">
                    <input type="hidden" name="user_id"
                           value="<?php echo $user->getUser_id(); ?>"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" id="red">
                </form>
            </td>"
                ;
            }
        }
        ?>

        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>    
    </table>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `<?php if(x): ?>` and `<?php endif ?>`see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php#112231

Comment: Yeah, here is my if statement:  if(isset($_SESSION['User'])){
            $adminOrNo =  $_SESSION['User']->getWlUserRoleID();
            if($adminOrNo == 2){
                *****this is where the two <td> buttons need to appear*****
                ;
            }
        }